# Internet explorer experiences "freeze" when first accessing math stackexchange

Tags: bug, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

When viewing Math Stackexchange using Internet Explorer (IE 9), a "freeze" is experienced when first accessing the website. What I mean is that the Internet Explorer browser momentarily becomes totally unresponsive for a few seconds (up to 15 seconds).

Although this isn't a problem after the 15 seconds, I would like to know what causes the problem (is it the loading of latex symbols?) and how to prevent it (if possible).

Also, anyone experiencing similar problems?

Sincere thanks!

[addon: This "freeze" only seems to happen on the main page of math.stackexchange.com, if I go directly to a question by clicking a link, without going to the main index page, it seems to be fine]

Comment: I've got the same problem using a FireFox 14.0.1 :-(. I blame MathJax, but I'm not sure...

Comment: I have no such problems using either Chrome or Firefox on my mac.

Comment: I'm using FF 13.0.1. When I go into math.SE I get a short pause (browser says "waiting for www.mathstackexchange.com") then another pause (browser says "waiting for www.gravatar.com"), then the first page appears which usually shows the raw Latex characters and after a few more seconds it appears again with the Latex correctly rendered. I've never thought of it as a bug: I assumed it was a combination of my OS (Vista) and my broadband speed and everything else that may have an effect.

Comment: I have the same issue using Chrome on my (old) laptop, which I believe is due to loading MathJax. Interestingly it only happens the first time in a session I load math.SE. It doesn't happen on my nice desktop.

Comment: @Alex I've got a laptop too. Yoyostein, what about you?

Comment: I think this is supposed to be fixed by the [incremental preview](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4208/a-prototype-for-incremental-preview-updates) script for MathJax, but Chrome doesn't want to install anything not from the Chrome store so I haven't been able to try it out.

Comment: @draks Yes I am using a laptop too.

Comment: I would start a bounty to get a solution for this annoying behaviour...

Comment: I actually have similar problem with chrome too.

Comment: Same thing here with chrome. The ~10 secs freeze happens systematically, but only once since boot.

Comment: This also happens to me with IE10.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with Firefox on Windows 7 and Windows Vista. I could fix it by deactivating hardware acceleration of the browser (which is activated by default in FF). In Firefox, go to Options => Advanced and uncheck the hardware acceleration box.

Answer (score 0):

I also have this problem using Windows 7 and Firefox 24.0: Firefox freezes for **more than 1 minute**. Nameless' fix doesn't work for me and deactivated nearly all firefox extensions (ok, I kept Wolfram). I forgot when this happened the first time, but now usually I could go *e.g.* fetching a beer, after clicking at http://math.stackexchange.com ...